# What is needed to make undocumented combinations of Tridion and Solr work with si4t?

Tags: si4t

Before realising that the default SI4T build is against Solr 4.4.0, I had already installed Solr 4.5.1 (dumb, I know, but I hadn't realised it was so fast-moving!). The SI4T documentation says you can "do a build yourself in case you need functionality of later versions of Solr", but I'm wondering whether I can expect any breakage if I run the pre-built jar against 4.5.1 (I guess there's some sort of breaking change at 4.4, but how often do they do that?) (This is unfamiliar tech for me: I'm willing to try it, but I'm not sure if I'd detect subtle breakage.)

Next up - how would I actually set it up. The documentation leaves it ["to the reader to mix the proper set of jar files in case this is needed."](https://github.com/SI4T/Solr/wiki/SI4T-Solr-Configuration-101#copying-additional-dependencies). So what process should I follow to determine what the correct set should be? Alternatively, if the correct answer is  "that's too hard, just install Solr 4.4 and go round", that would also be helpful.

Edit: I'm on Tridion 2011, although the question is really about the process.

Answer (score 7):

Solr moves very fast indeed. Yesterday version [4.6.0](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/solrnews.html) was released and its quite likely that more minor version updates will be coming soon.

The good thing is that the actual library that SI4T uses to index content in SOLR, which is called [SolrJ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJava), always guarantees backward and cross-version compatibility for Solr's minor version updates, as is stated [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#SolrJ.2FSolr_cross-version_compatibility).

This basically means that SI4T can use the same SolrJ library across the 4.x versions for Solr, so the current build of SI4T against version 4.4.0 would also work for Solr 4.5.1, since the API is backward compatible.

That said, it is of course imperative to regularly release newer builds, in order to be able to use new features and fixes that come out with each Solr release.

So, to summarize a final answer:

1. You should be able to use the current build of SI4T against Solr 4.5.1;
2. If you want full version matching, for the short term install the Solr 4.4.0 war file
3. The SI4T team will release two new branche builds for Tridion 2013 with Solr 4.5.1 and Solr 4.6.0 support in the very near future (december 2013), so you could also wait for that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Raimond. I'm still trying to understand the jar dependencies. Are there some jars that are needed both for Tridion and the Solr client?

Comment: There are indeed a couple of shared jars - mainly the XML processing ones and logging (slf4j). I'll put the full dependency list online somewhere this week. :)